# Passing value through url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to send a url from view page to controller but it does not seem to work the way i am thinking.

**View Page**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/test/product/tbl_product">Product</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/test/user/tbl_user">User</a>
```

I want to get "tbl_product"
**Controller admin**

```
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
  public function test() {
  echo $this->uri->segment(4);
  }
}
?>
```

but if the segment(4) is changed to segment(3), it shows up with displaying "product" in the screen

Comment: I don't see any error here. `segment 4` should be `tbl_product`. Are you inside `test` function?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam Only a blank page appears. Didnt help with segment(4). I am inside `test` function.

Comment: provide your routes found in `application\config\routes.php`

Comment: @CodeGodie `$route['default_controller'] = "admin";
$route['404_override'] = '';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller function should have arguments for your url segments

for example:

```
 public function test($product = 'product', $tbl = 'tbl_product') {
     echo $tbl // contains the string tbl_product
 }
```

Comment: if not, then you need to configure this in your `routes.php`

Comment: This better way to program but this will produce error if the link is ...baseurl/admin/test

Comment: not when you use default values, I changed my code, have a look :)

Comment: @AgeDeO Default values works, but I have multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your routes look like this:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "admin"; 
$route['404_override'] = ''
```

and your URL is like this:

```
<?= base_url() ?>admin/test/product/tbl_product
```

Then if your base_url() is `localhost/my_app`, your URL will be read as this:

```
http://localhost/my_app/admin/test/product/tbl_product
http://localhost/my_app/CONTROLLER/METHOD/PARAMETER/PARAMETER
```

So in your controller, you can do this:

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function test($product = NULL, $tbl_product = NULL) {
        echo $product; 
        echo $tbl_product; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to use codeigniter for this purpose, because codeigniter uses as default the url format bellow.

"[base_url]/[controller]/[method]"

I think it will be better and more easy to just pass the values you want as get parameters and make some httaccess rules to make your url more readable for the user and robots. That said you can do that:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/test?product=tbl_product">Product</a>

<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller {
  public function test() {
  echo $this->input->get('product');
  //should output 'tbl_product'
  }
}
?>
```

If you prefer to use uri instead u should route your uri's so it will be like.

In your routes file you probably I'll need something like this.

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "Admin/test";
```

This way you will probably access the uri segments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for going through.

```
$this->uri->segment(4); // is now working :S
```

its not working properly after all I made changes to routes.php and came back to default again. I seriously have no idea what the reason behind not displaying the result before.